# How to use ConcurrentLinkedQueue?

Tags: java, concurrency

How do I use a `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` in Java?
Using this `LinkedQueue`, do I need to be worried about concurrency in the queue? Or do I just have to define two methods (one to retrive elements from the list and another to add elements to the list)?
Note: obviously these two methods have to be synchronized. Right?

---

**EDIT:** What I'm trying to do is this: I have a class (in Java) with one method to retrieve items from the queue and another class with one method to add items to the queue. The items added and retrieved from the list are objects of my own class.

One more question: do I need to do this in the remove method:

```
while (queue.size() == 0){ 
  wait(); 
  queue.poll();
}
```

I only have one consumer and one producer.

Comment: Thanks for the response to mt question.
What i'm trying to do is this: i have a class (in Java) with one method to retrieve items from the queue and another class with one method to add items to the queue. 

The items added and retrieved from the list are objects of my own class.

Comment: You should edit your question and put this clarification in the question itself.

Answer (score 165, accepted):

No, the methods don't need to be synchronized, and you don't need to define any methods; they are already in ConcurrentLinkedQueue, just use them. ConcurrentLinkedQueue does all the locking and other operations you need internally; your producer(s) adds data into the queue, and your consumers poll for it.

First, create your queue:

```
Queue<YourObject> queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<YourObject>();
```

Now, wherever you are creating your producer/consumer objects, pass in the queue so they have somewhere to put their objects (you could use a setter for this, instead, but I prefer to do this kind of thing in a constructor):

```
YourProducer producer = new YourProducer(queue);
```

and:

```
YourConsumer consumer = new YourConsumer(queue);
```

and add stuff to it in your producer:

```
queue.offer(myObject);
```

and take stuff out in your consumer (if the queue is empty, poll() will return null, so check it):

```
YourObject myObject = queue.poll();
```

For more info see [the Javadoc](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html)

## EDIT:

If you need to block waiting for the queue to not be empty, you probably want to use a [LinkedBlockingQueue](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html), and use the take() method. However, LinkedBlockingQueue has a maximum capacity (defaults to Integer.MAX_VALUE, which is over two billion) and thus may or may not be appropriate depending on your circumstances.

If you only have one thread putting stuff into the queue, and another thread taking stuff out of the queue, ConcurrentLinkedQueue is probably overkill. It's more for when you may have hundreds or even thousands of threads accessing the queue at the same time. Your needs will probably be met by using:

```
Queue<YourObject> queue = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<YourObject>());
```

A plus of this is that it locks on the instance (queue), so you can synchronize on queue to ensure atomicity of composite operations (as explained by Jared). You CANNOT do this with a ConcurrentLinkedQueue, as all operations are done WITHOUT locking on the instance (using java.util.concurrent.atomic variables). You will NOT need to do this if you want to block while the queue is empty, because poll() will simply return null while the queue is empty, and poll() is atomic. Check to see if poll() returns null. If it does, wait(), then try again. No need to lock.

## Finally:

Honestly, I'd just use a LinkedBlockingQueue. It is still overkill for your application, but odds are it will work fine. If it isn't performant enough (PROFILE!), you can always try something else, and it means you don't have to deal with ANY synchronized stuff:

```
BlockingQueue<YourObject> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<YourObject>();

queue.put(myObject); // Blocks until queue isn't full.

YourObject myObject = queue.take(); // Blocks until queue isn't empty.
```

Everything else is the same. Put *probably* won't block, because you aren't likely to put two billion objects into the queue.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
One more question: do i need to do this in the remove method:
while (queue.size() == 0)
   wait();
queue.poll();

Comment: I'll answer that as an edit to my answer, since it's pretty important.

Comment: As caused confusion in another question, `Collection.synchronizedList` returns a `List` which does not implement `Queue`.

Comment: @AdamJaskiewicz is using `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` for Producer Consumer a good idea, I am referring to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426754/linkedblockingqueue-vs-concurrentlinkedqueue?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 39):

This is largely a [duplicate of another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435069/java-util-concurrentlinkedqueue/435941#435941).

Here's the section of that answer that is relevant to this question:

**Do I need to do my own synchronization if I use java.util.ConcurrentLinkedQueue?**

Atomic operations on the concurrent collections are synchronized for you.  In other words, each individual call to the queue is guaranteed thread-safe without any action on your part.  What is **not** guaranteed thread-safe are any operations you perform on the collection that are non-atomic.

For example, this is threadsafe without any action on your part:

```
queue.add(obj);
```

or

```
queue.poll(obj);
```

However; non-atomic calls to the queue are not automatically thread-safe.  For example, the following operations are **not** automatically threadsafe:

```
if(!queue.isEmpty()) {
   queue.poll(obj);
}
```

That last one is not threadsafe, as it is very possible that between the time isEmpty is called and the time poll is called, other threads will have added or removed items from the queue.  The threadsafe way to perform this is like this:

```
synchronized(queue) {
    if(!queue.isEmpty()) {
       queue.poll(obj);
    }
}
```

Again...atomic calls to the queue are automatically thread-safe.  Non-atomic calls are not.

Comment: The only common use I can thing of is blocking until the queue is non-empty. Would that not be better served by using an implementation of BlockingQueue (take() is atomic and blocks until there is something to consume)?

Comment: Also you need to be careful with that. Unlike synchronizedList, ConcurrentLinkedQueue doesn't synchronize on itself, so in your code it would still be possible for a producer to offer to the queue while you are in your synchronized block.

Comment: Why would you combine queue.isEmpty() and queue.poll()? Can't you just poll and check if the result is null? (my understanding is that if you poll an empty queue it returns null)

Comment: I agree with everything in your code except the last code block.
Synchronizing on the ConcurrentLInkedQueue does not guarantee you anything because other calls are not synchronised. So there could be an "add(..)" happening from another thread between your "isEmpty()" and "poll(...)" even though you have synchronised this thread

Answer (score 8):

This is probably what you're looking for in terms of thread safety & "prettyness" when trying to consume everything in the queue:

```
for (YourObject obj = queue.poll(); obj != null; obj = queue.poll()) {
}
```

This will guarantee that you quit when the queue is empty, and that you continue to pop objects off of it as long as it's not empty.

Comment: Very useful for emptying a queue. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Use [poll](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html#poll()) to get the first element, and [add](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html#add(E)) to add a new last element. That's it, no synchronization or anything else.

Answer (score 2):

The ConcurentLinkedQueue is a very efficient wait/lock free implementation (see the javadoc for reference), so not only you don't need to synchronize, but the queue will not lock anything, thus being virtually as fast as a non synchronized (not thread safe) one.

Answer (score 1):

Just use it as you would a non-concurrent collection. The Concurrent[Collection] classes wrap the regular collections so that you don't have to think about synchronizing access.

**Edit:** ConcurrentLinkedList isn't actually just a wrapper, but rather a better concurrent implementation. Either way, you don't have to worry about synchronization.

Comment: ConcurrentLinkedQueue isn't. It's specifically built from the ground up for concurrent access by multiple producers and consumers. A bit fancier than the simple wrappers returned by Collections.synchronized*

Comment: Yeah, there were a lot of neat concurrency things added in J2SE 5.