# Java: What object is more appropriate?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, vector, arraylist

I am writing an application similar to a chat server-client pair.

I am planning on having a central Object which will hold new messages received from clients until they are dealt with by the main thread.

My application is multi-threaded. Each client will be on its own thread, so multiple threads will be adding messages to this central Object.

The main thread will check this Object for messages, remove the "oldest" and deal with it appropriately. Preferably I would like the messages to be handled in the same order they were added (FIFO).

What type of Object is most appropriate to hold the new messages? I looked into Vectors and ArrayLists, but I am confused about the synchronization aspect. I never worked with synchronization or threads before.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ConcurrentLinkedQueue` sounds likely.

More info here: [How to use ConcurrentLinkedQueue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616484/how-to-use-concurrentlinkedqueue)

Javadoc here: http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html

Answer (score 3):

If this is to become more than a little toy project, you should look into [JMS](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-142945.html) which solves all of the little problems that you're not aware of, yet.

A good implementation of JMS is [Apache ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/) (not related to IBM's MQSeries).

Comment: As much as I love AMQ (and JMS) I disagree in this case *unless* the OP requires either message persistence or multiple consumers (in different processes) of said messages.  They didn't indicate either.  JMS becomes a bit too heavyweight in this case.

Comment: As I said: "If it's a serious project" which means: If you need all the usual things like protection against losing messages, duplicate messages, transactions, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You may also consider [jgroups](http://www.jgroups.org/) for this project.

JGroups is an open source reliable group communication toolkit. Its reliable and simple to use. Here is a basic [chat example](http://www.jgroups.org/tutorial/html/ch02.html) in the tutorial of same.

Answer (score 1):

While not a direct answer (As @Alison provided a decent enough of one provided you don't need to persist messages) always have a look at the java.util.concurrent package whenever you need data structure classes or utility classes to help with multi-threaded coded:  http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html