# Synchronized collections list

Tags: java, list, linked-list, queue, synchronized

I have 2 threads needing access to a Queue, one for putting and one for getting.

So I have an initiation

```
public static Queue<WorldData>          blockDestructionQueue   = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<WorldData>());
```

With the above I get a Type mismatch: cannot convert from List to Queue

I tried casting it to a Queue but this did not work.

```
public static Queue<WorldData>          blockDestructionQueue   = (Queue<WorldData>)Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<WorldData>());
```

I was wondering as to why this is not working.

I got this information from another stack overflow answer.

[How to use ConcurrentLinkedQueue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616484/how-to-use-concurrentlinkedqueue)

In the correct answer paragraph 6

> If you only have one thread putting stuff into the queue, and another
>   thread taking stuff out of the queue, ConcurrentLinkingQueue is
>   probably overkill. It's more for when you may have hundreds or even
>   thousands of threads accessing the queue at the same time. Your needs
>   will probably be met by using:
>
> ```
> Queue<YourObject> queue = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<YourObject>());
> ```
>
> A plus of this is that it locks on the instance (queue), so you can
>   synchronize on queue to ensure atomicity of composite operations (as
>   explained by Jared). You CANNOT do this with a ConcurrentLinkingQueue,
>   as all operations are done WITHOUT locking on the instance (using
>   java.util.concurrent.atomic variables). You will NOT need to do this
>   if you want to block while the queue is empty, because poll() will
>   simply return null while the queue is empty, and poll() is atomic.
>   Check to see if poll() returns null. If it does, wait(), then try
>   again. No need to lock.

Additional Information:

edit: Eclipse was trying to be too helpful and decided to add a break point exception where it was not needed and was not asked to put one.

Comment: "Correct" answer are not necessarily entirely correct.

Comment: A List is not a Queue - why not use a LinkedBlockingQueue; it is designed for this pattern. The consumer will block while the List is empty.

Comment: The reason why I did not use a LinkedBlockingQueue is due to what the "Correct" answer stated in his post where LinkedBlockingQueue would be more intensive than a SyncronizedList

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A queue is not a list and a `Queue` is not an implementation of `List`, although you can implement a queue with a list.

Have a look at BlockingQueue it is probably a better fit for what you need:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html

Comment: I tried implementing this but have got the following error Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error on token "(", Expression expected after 
  this token
 - Syntax error on token "(", Expression expected after 
  this token     with public static BlockingQueue<WorldData>   blockDestructionQueue = LinkedBlockingQueue<WorldData>();

Comment: Don't forget the keyword 'new', its very (very very) important. ;)

Comment: Also, some StackOverflow newbie advice - Don't forget to upvote the answers that help you, and accept the answer that answers your problem.

Answer (score 0):

`Collections.synchronizedList` returns an instance of `SynchronizedList` which does not extend `Queue`.  `LinkedList` is a `Queue` but that's not what you're using at that point.