# How to acess values of a ArrayList on a different threads in a multi-threaded java program

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, collections

My doubt is that , is there any option that i can get values in `Arraylist` , that is added by the first thread , from the second thread and so on.
And each thread will be modifying the list and updated list need to be available for all the threads .

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: @PramodYadav: That would do nothing useful.

Comment: You can achieve this with proper synchronization. But it is probably better to use a different data structure from the `java.util.concurrent` package if you need to communicate between threads. They have spezialized collections for things like queues.

Comment: An example for using a queue: [How to use ConcurrentLinkedQueue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616484/how-to-use-concurrentlinkedqueue)

Answer (score 2):

You can use  [java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try to create synchronized **ArrayList** using **Collections** class **static** method.

Below arraylist will be synchronized :

```
List<String> synArraylist = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());
```