# ConcurrentLinkedQueue: How to implement a handler in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, queue, listener, handler

lets say we have two threads with are connected by a ConcurrentLinkedQueue. What  I want is something like a handler on the queue so that one thread knows when the other queue has added soemthing to the queue and to poll it. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/435069/java-util-concurrentlinkedqueue/435941#435941

Comment: If you use a Blocking queue, you can just call `take` on it.  It will return when an element is available.

Comment: but I want it to be async

Comment: Then you need a spin, you cannot get both blocking and async features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally a `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` is used when there is at least one producer on a thread, and at least one consumer on a different thread.

The consumer will process the element as soon as they are available, to do so the read operation on the queue blocks, sometimes for a limited amount of time.

Depending on the application you can have a single producer and many consumer, or viceversa.

Blocking achieves exactly your requirement (the consumer thread knows when an element is inserted).

The fact that the consumer thread blocks is not a problem unless is your main process thread or unless you are planning to build several hundred concurrent consumers.

So, Queue#take() or Queue#poll(long timeout,TimeUnit unit) is your friend here, if you just run it on dedicated Thread.